# Oracle 12cr2 PRAGMA DEPRECATE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

We are attempting to clean up our PLSQL code base as it is scattered across may different schemas and want to use the `PRAGMA DEPRECATE` functionality to identify areas where these UDF's/Procs are being used in order to update them with UDF's/Procs from our centralized schema.
But when i recompile a view that uses the deprecated function i am not getting any sort of warning for the view.

Have a function in package that has been successfully deprecated.
    `[Warning] PLW-06019 (13: 5): PLW-06019: entity FunctionName is deprecated`

I have enabled PLSQL warnings.
    `ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='ENABLE:(6019,6020,6021,6022)';`

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE schemaName.PackageName
    AS
    FUNCTION FunctionName (p_NumIn NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2;
    PRAGMA DEPRECATE(FunctionName);
    END schemaName.PackageName;
```

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW schemaName.ViewName
    (
        FunctionColumnName
    )
    BEQUEATH DEFINER
    AS
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            schemaName.FunctionName (ColumnNameNumVal)
        FROM TableName
        WHERE
            TableName.ColumnNameInd IS NULL;
```

I expected when i compiled the view for there to be a compilation error indicating the function used in the selection statement has been deprecated. There was no error provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLSQL_WARNINGS only applies to PL/SQL program units. These are [defined in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/overview.html#GUID-DF63BC59-22C2-4BA8-9240-F74D505D5102) as

> PL/SQL anonymous block
>   FUNCTION
>   LIBRARY
>   PACKAGE
>   PACKAGE BODY
>   PROCEDURE
>   TRIGGER
>   TYPE
>   TYPE BODY

The list does not include Views, alas, because Views are SQL and not PL/SQL. I agree it would be neat if the deprecation warnings were propagated to Views (and there's a similar lacuna for tables with column built out of Types). But I suspect Oracle decided the effort involved in changing the SQL compiler to check PLSQL_WARNINGS greatly outweighs the potential benefit (percentage of Oracle customers writing views which depend on user-defined functions? percentage of those customers who use the deprecation pragma?).

Comment: Are you aware of anyway to identify deprecated functions that are used in SQL?
Some other package or functionality?